# How do I get max value for a specific corresponding column when I have 3 other corresponding columns?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 4 columns:
URL | keywords | Volume (of keyword) | Position (of Keyword)

is there a way I can pull the max(volume) for the URL? I also want to pull in keyword and position column, but I have multiple values per URL, so when I add the other columns I get back more data than I want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group

Answer (score 0):

Not clear on the question ,if you mean that you need maximum volume for a given url while retaining the other columns ,here is the code :
Select url,keywords,position,(select max(volume) from your_table t1 where t1.url=t.url)
From your_table t

Comment: so I only want 1 result per URL